# Implementing auto-renewable subscriptions

Tags: in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I am implementing an auto-renewable subscription giving a free trial for a week. I want to generate payments automatically in the 8th day. I am adding card details before the free trial starts. 
Is there any best tutorial to implement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I am adding card details before the free trial starts" - do you mean you're handling the payment yourself? You'll need to use in-app purchase products if you're selling digital content or else your app will be rejected.

Comment: The question is too vague. Please add more technical details for e.g. platform Android or iOS, the library used, how you implemented the in-app purchase. And As far as I know, there is no way you can get card details or provide it to the In-App purchase library.